# Sandbox alike solution for linux

Tags: mount, chroot, bind, sandbox

I wonder if there is a kind of a sandboxing solution for linux, sometimes there is more than one app that is candidate to solve my problems, in that case I want to try all of them to get the one which better fit my needs.

Usually I extract .deb files somewhere and export `PATH` env adding the bin directory and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` adding the lib direcotry. Most of the times it works well, but sometimes the application requires /etc configurations, or other resources like images on share folder, that I was not able to solve.

My [test machine is old](http://pastebin.com/i0NBC8VG), so I have low resources, a VM would bore me a lot, a separated linux installation in my disk doing chroot would please me better than a VM in performance, but it still takes some unwanted spaces because of repeated files, almost all of them are the same of my original distro.

I was wondering if there is somehow a mixed mount -bind with some magic flag, or other solution, something like the follow:

```
$ mkdir dir1 dir2
$ echo "Lipsum" > dir1/file1
$ echo "Original" > dir1/file2
$ sudo mount -o bind -some-magic-flag dir1 dir2
$ echo "Changed" > dir2/file2
$ touch dir2/file3
$ ls -1 dir2
file1
file2
file3
# it's ok
$ ls -1 dir1
file1
file2
# file3 sould not be here!
$ sudo umount dir2
$ ls -1 dir2
file2
file3
# file1 was not changed, should not be repeated here, but file2 was
$ cat dir1/file2
Original
$ cat dir2/file2
Changed
```

Comment: I assume you read through some of the 3,550,000 results that Google gives for "Linux sandbox" right?

Comment: @terdon I found [this one](http://sandbox.sourceforge.net/) but I thought it isn't finished yet.

Comment: Random google results: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4249063/1081936), [two](http://askubuntu.com/questions/292925/how-to-sandbox-applications) and [three](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/382226-run-applications-in-secure-sandboxes-with-selinux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was possible with overlayfs:

mount -t overlay -o "lowerdir=/original,upperdir=/overlay,workdir=/tmp/workdir" overlay /mnt/target

Where `/original` is untouched, `/overlay` is the result of changes on `/mnt/target` over `/original`, thus `/mnt/target` is the result of files in `/original` plus files in `/overlay`.

The `/tmp/work` is a control directory, it is necessary while the mount exists, but it is not necessary to remain after umount.

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation would be to switch to BSD and run jail, but I'm assuming you don't want that. So instead I'll recommend [Dockers](https://www.docker.io/), which is basically a way to isolate an application from the rest of the system.